# Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch, When multiplying assigned variables

Tags: vba

As the title explains that is the error I'm getting where NETPRICE = NET * TOTWIDTH and NET = "PRODUCTBOX.LIST(PRODUCTBOX.ListIndex, 2)". Still getting used to VBA. I tried reassigning the variables as Integers but that didn't help. Any suggestions?

```
Private Sub ADDBTN_Click()
Dim THRESWIDTH As Variant
Dim THRESWIDTHRND As Variant
Dim TOTWIDTH As Integer
Dim NET As Variant
Dim THRES_DES As String
Dim THRESHOLD As String
Dim FINISH As String
Dim NETPRICE As Integer

THRESWIDTH = InputBox("WHAT IS THE WIDTH OF THE THRESHOLD IN INCHES?        (i.e. 36,36 1/2)")

TOTWIDTH = Application.RoundUp(THRESWIDTH / 12, 0)

THRESWIDTHRND = TOTWIDTH * 12

If FINISHBOX.Value = "A - MILL FINISH ALUMINUM" Then
    NET = "PRODUCTBOX.LIST(PRODUCTBOX.ListIndex, 2)"
ElseIf FINISHBOX.Value = "B - MILL FINISH EXTRUDED BRONZE (BRASS)" Then
    NET = "PRODUCTBOX.LIST(PRODUCTBOX.ListIndex, 4)"
ElseIf FINISHBOX.Value = "D - DARK BRONZE ANODIZED" Then
    NET = "PRODUCTBOX.LIST(PRODUCTBOX.ListIndex, 6)"
ElseIf FINISHBOX.Value = "G - GOLD ANODIZED" Then
    NET = "PRODUCTBOX.LIST(PRODUCTBOX.ListIndex, 8)"
Else
End If

NETPRICE = NET * TOTWIDTH
```

Comment: `NET` is a string, `TOTWIDTH` is an integer. (which is **exactly** what the error message says with *Type mismatch*). What would you expect multiplying a string by an integer to produce if it *was* allowed? Remove the quotes around the values you're assigning to `NET`, and make it a numeric type instead of a Variant.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Ken White, Was a long day and was in a hurry. Makes sense that it the error was mismatch opps.

Answer (score 0):

Figured It out, Variable were not assigned properly and had to put Val() around my string variables.

```
Private Sub ADDBTN_Click()
Dim THRESWIDTH As Variant
Dim THRESWIDTHRND As Variant
Dim TOTWIDTH As Integer
Dim NET As Variant
Dim THRES_DES As String
Dim THRESHOLD As String
Dim FINISH As String
Dim NETPRICE As Variant
Dim NETA As Variant
Dim NETB As Variant
Dim NETD As Variant
Dim NETG As Variant

THRESWIDTH = InputBox("WHAT IS THE WIDTH OF THE THRESHOLD IN INCHES?        (i.e. 36,36 1/2)")

TOTWIDTH = Application.RoundUp(THRESWIDTH / 12, 0)

THRESWIDTHRND = Val(TOTWIDTH) * 12


NETA = PRODUCTBOX.LIST(PRODUCTBOX.ListIndex, 2)
NETB = PRODUCTBOX.LIST(PRODUCTBOX.ListIndex, 4)
NETD = PRODUCTBOX.LIST(PRODUCTBOX.ListIndex, 6)
NETG = PRODUCTBOX.LIST(PRODUCTBOX.ListIndex, 8)

If FINISHBOX.Value = "A - MILL FINISH ALUMINUM" Then
    NET = Val(NETA)
ElseIf FINISHBOX.Value = "B - MILL FINISH EXTRUDED BRONZE (BRASS)" Then
   NET = Val(NETB)
ElseIf FINISHBOX.Value = "D - DARK BRONZE ANODIZED" Then
   NET = Val(NETD)
ElseIf FINISHBOX.Value = "G - GOLD ANODIZED" Then
NET = Val(NETG)
Else
End If

NETPRICE = Val(NET) * Val(TOTWIDTH)
```

Comment: Try using `Application.InputBox` instead of Inputbox. There you can specify the input type (e.g. only number).

Comment: Thanks @vacip I will try that out.